# Potential Bug with JSON Decoder Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoder, decoder

I believe I have found a bug in the JSONDecoder. If one tries to decode a JSON object with more than 8 properties, I get an unrecognizable error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXCBADACCESS (code=1,
> address=0xe8). The process has been left at the point where it was
> interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before
> expression evaluation.

This error happens whenever I execute code similar to below:

```
struct Objects: Codable {
  var NAME1: String?
  var NAME2: String?
  var NAME3: String?
  var NAME4: String?
  var NAME5: String?
  var NAME6: String?
  var NAME7: String?
  var NAME8: String?
  var NAME9: String?
}
let NEWDATA = """
[
{
  "NAME1": "hi",
  "NAME2": "hi",
  "NAME3": "hi",
  "NAME4": "hi",
  "NAME5": "hi",
  "NAME6": "hi",
  "NAME7": "hi",
  "NAME8": "hi",
  "NAME9": "HELLO"
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder2 = JSONDecoder()
let product2 = try decoder2.decode([Objects].self, from: NEWDATA)
print(product2)
```

This happens in both the Playground and on the device. Maybe I am doing something wrong but it works when you have only 8 properties in the Objects struct but not when you have 9 or more.

Xcode Version: 12.1

Swift Version: 5.3

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: That's indeed and issue in the Playground but I am not seeing it in the Simulator.

Comment: Works fine for me in a macOS playground using Xcode 12.2 beta and also iOS playground

Comment: @JoakimDanielson probably your playground is macOS

Comment: I've seen this before with iOS playgrounds

Comment: I can run it in both macOS and iOS playgrounds so most likely it is the Xcode version

Comment: In macOS playgrounds works fine for me also. I was wondering earlier today, why I get this error :)

Comment: working for me as well iOS playground Xcode 12.1

Comment: Well, after one successful run with macOS playgrounds, now works with iOS also.

Comment: And after restarting Xcode 12.1 the bug returns...

Comment: Thank you all for your help @gcharita.  I tried it in MacOS playground and it worked and then swapped it back to iOS and that seems to fix the bug in playground.

Comment: Discussed - but not resolved - here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665159

Comment: Have submitted a ticket on Feedback Assistant: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9078075

Comment: Now believe this is unrelated to JSONDecoder. It is the struct initialisation with nine properties that causes the execution abort.

Answer (score 3):

Noted @TheSlyTurtle that you also raised this [JSONDecoder Limit](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665159) issue on Apple Developer Forums.

Another user Claude31 and myself independently raised feedback on Feedback Assistant. See FB9080056 and FB9393489.

Apple replied on this 27 July 2021 as follows:

> Hi Max,
>
> Thanks for your patience, and for your feedback.  Please verify
> whether this is still an issue in Xcode 13 beta. There have been tools
> updates since this was filed, and this issue is not seen in our tests.
>
> Please test with the latest betas, and then update your feedback
> report with your results by logging into
> https://feedbackassistant.apple.com or by using the Feedback Assistant
> app.
>
> Xcode 13, macOS 12 and iOS 15 Betas and Release Candidates:
> https://developer.apple.com/download/
>
> If the issue continues, please provide appropriate fresh logs and
> screen recordings:
> https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/
>
> Please close this report if resolved, or let us know if still an issue
> for you.  Thank you.
>
> Feedback ID 9080056, Playground Execution Abort With Struct On Ninth
> Property
>
> Do not reply to this email. Please login to Feedback Assistant to view
> this request.

Both myself and Claude31 stated that as of Xcode 13 beta 4 (13A5201i) this defect no longer manifests.