# Swift JSONDecoder is showing different values than what is actually in the JSON tree

Tags: json, swift

I'm setting up a function to decode a JSON tree into various structs in Swift. I'm testing in a playground. The JSON tree is complex so I won't bother posting the whole thing, but the part I'm focused on is this:

```json
"overall":{
   "score":424224,
   "scorePerMin":25.093,
   "scorePerMatch":104.232,
   "wins":180,
   "top3":199,
   "top5":339,
   "top6":312,
   "top10":250,
   "top12":619,
   "top25":479,
   "kills":5830,
   "killsPerMin":0.345,
   "killsPerMatch":1.432,
   "deaths":3890,
   "kd":1.499,
   "matches":4070,
   "winRate":4.423,
   "minutesPlayed":16906,
   "playersOutlived":120646,
   "lastModified":"2020-12-14T00:43:12Z"
}
```

I've verified that this is the JSON tree being decoded, it isn't getting modified in any way.

Observe these two tests and their outcomes:

`Test 1`
Notice: 6 variables in the structure

```swift
public struct overall: Decodable {
    var score : Int? = 0
    var scorePerMin : Double? = 0.0
    var scorePerMatch : Double? = 0.0
    var wins : Int? = 0
    var top3 : Int? = 0
    var top5 : Int? = 0
    //var top6 : Int? = 0
    //var top10 : Int? = 0
    //var top12 : Int? = 0
    //var top25 : Int? = 0
    //var kills : Int? = 0
    //var killsPerMin : Double? = 0.0
    //var killsPerMatch : Double? = 0.0
    //var deaths : Int? = 0
    //var kd : Double? = 0.0
    //var matches : Int? = 0
    //var winRate : Double? = 0.0
    //var minutesPlayed : Int? = 0
    //var playersOutlived : Int? = 0
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case score = "score"
        case scorePerMin = "scorePerMin"
        case scorePerMatch = "scorePerMatch"
        case wins = "wins"
        case top3 = "top3"
        case top5 = "top5"
        //case top6 = "top6"
        //case top10 = "top10"
        //case top12 = "top12"
        //case top25 = "top25"
        //case kills = "kills"
        //case killsPerMin = "killsPerMin"
        //case killsPerMatch = "killsPerMatch"
        //case deaths = "deaths"
        //case kd = "kd"
        //case matches = "matches"
        //case winRate = "winRate"
        //case minutesPlayed = "minutesPlayed"
        //case playersOutlived = "playersOutlived"
        
    }
}
```

Test 1 Console Output (As Expected)

> overall: Optional(__lldb_expr_163.overall(score: Optional(424224), scorePerMin: Optional(25.093), scorePerMatch: Optional(104.232), wins: Optional(180), top3: Optional(199), top5: Optional(339)))

`Test 2`
Notice: 8 variables in the structure

```swift
public struct overall: Decodable {
    var score : Int? = 0
    var scorePerMin : Double? = 0.0
    var scorePerMatch : Double? = 0.0
    var wins : Int? = 0
    var top3 : Int? = 0
    var top5 : Int? = 0
    var top6 : Int? = 0
    var top10 : Int? = 0
    //var top12 : Int? = 0
    //var top25 : Int? = 0
    //var kills : Int? = 0
    //var killsPerMin : Double? = 0.0
    //var killsPerMatch : Double? = 0.0
    //var deaths : Int? = 0
    //var kd : Double? = 0.0
    //var matches : Int? = 0
    //var winRate : Double? = 0.0
    //var minutesPlayed : Int? = 0
    //var playersOutlived : Int? = 0
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case score = "score"
        case scorePerMin = "scorePerMin"
        case scorePerMatch = "scorePerMatch"
        case wins = "wins"
        case top3 = "top3"
        case top5 = "top5"
        case top6 = "top6"
        case top10 = "top10"
        //case top12 = "top12"
        //case top25 = "top25"
        //case kills = "kills"
        //case killsPerMin = "killsPerMin"
        //case killsPerMatch = "killsPerMatch"
        //case deaths = "deaths"
        //case kd = "kd"
        //case matches = "matches"
        //case winRate = "winRate"
        //case minutesPlayed = "minutesPlayed"
        //case playersOutlived = "playersOutlived"
        
    }
}
```

Test 2 Console Output (Random Numbers)
If I run the code again, the numbers become slightly different.

> overall: Optional(__lldb_expr_175.overall(score: Optional(123145305732784), scorePerMin: Optional(5e-324), scorePerMatch: Optional(-nan(0x39ffffd70e390)), wins: Optional(123145305732920), top3: Optional(123145305732896), top5: Optional(-105553120400160), top6: Optional(140735453566400), top10: Optional(123145305732936)))

EDIT: Here is the playground file: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/09C328eVvJsVhBj8CLXgbjeBA#Fortnite

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a playground. Some off-topic notes, custom types should start with an uppercase letter so it should be `struct Overall`, can really every property be nil in the struct, use optional only when needed and lastly you don't need a CodingKey enum if all property names are the same as the json key names.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've added the link to the Playground file. See if you can reproduce my problem.

Comment: I have tried the Playground file on Xcode 12.4 and could reproduce the issue. But when I copied all the code into a simple project, it worked as expected with no problem. Better send a feedback to Apple as a Playground bug.

Comment: Probably the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598849/potential-bug-with-json-decoder-swift

Comment: @OOPer I appreciate that. Thank you